# Typeorm intenta crear tablas que ya existen

Tags: typescript, typeorm

Estoy empezando a usar typeorm ya que quiero utilizar Socket.io. He seguido los pasos para crear una conexión pero al lanzarla me da un error de que la tabla que estoy referenciando en entities (En mi caso models) ya existe en la base de datos. En caso de que no exista la está creando. Como puedo solucionar el error para que me traiga los datos correctamente?

Este es el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la parte del typeorm:

```
{
    "type": "mssql",
    "host": "LAPTOP-T76T7RH8",
    "username": "isri",
    "password": "isri",
    "database": "Animales",
    "entities": ["build/models/**/*.js"],
    "logging": false,
    "synchronize": true
}
```

Este es el modelo:

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm'

@Entity()
export class Peces {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id_pez: number;

    @Column()
    nombre: string;

    @Column()
    tamaño: number;
}
```

Este es el controller:

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';


import { Peces } from "../models/Peces";
import { getConnection, getRepository } from "typeorm";

export const getPeces = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> => {
  const users = await getRepository(Peces).find();
  return res.json(users);
};
```

Muchas gracias! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quitando el synchronize del fichero ormconfig.json se arregla

```
{
    "type": "mssql",
    "host": "LAPTOP-T76T7RH8",
    "port": 1433,
    "username": "isri",
    "password": "isri",
    "database": "Animales",
    "entities": ["build/models/**/*.js"],
    "logging": false,
}
```